# Czech declension of Masculine Names ending in -a

Tags: grammar, declension, czech

I have come across several examples where at least in the genitive of a two-word phrase the name ending -a does not decline, e.g., svatého Sáva (vs. standard and more common Sávy), Alexandra (or Cesara) Borgia (not sure if the standard form is attested). Now in a 14th cent text we do find Crha (the Czech name of Constantine the Philosopher) handled like this (e.g. svatého Crha).  Till now this has always been taken to mean that this name was actually analyzed as Crh or Crho by the author but that seems impossible since the same text repeatedly uses the nom. Crha and the acc. Crhu.  What I would like to ask is whether there are other OLD examples of this kind of syntax (which I think requires that another word in the phrase have explicit genitive marking)?  Next, what native speakers today feel about it (is it f.ex. more common that I know because the written texts are in effect self-censored)?  Finally, does anybody know whether the manuscripts of the Old Czech Pasionál have the uninflected Crha or only the printed 1495 book or how to find out. Maybe the whole passage is not in any preserved ms.?

Comment: This sounds very unnatural to me and I did have read some Old Czech stuff before. Can you point to the actual sources?

Comment: Hopefully it will be useful to others: ["o vieře svatého Crha se diviece"](https://vokabular.ujc.cas.cz/moduly/edicni/edice/125a0032-03b5-40ec-b68d-80473cc5653a/plny-text/bez-aparatu/folio/93r) BTW, you could have mentioned that you asked at [WordReference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/czech-declension-masc-names-in-a.4083596/#post-20977778) before and received some answer.

Comment: I found "svatého Sáva" even in a [modern thesis](https://dspace.cuni.cz/bitstream/handle/20.500.11956/70427/120186379.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y). However, it seems to be just sloppy writing to me, most other hits are just machine translations.

Comment: Thank you but I dont see why you're yelling at me.  I didnt mention WR because the answer I got was not useful.  Nor do I see why if someone writes something you don't like it has to be "sloppy".  I am asking politely for information, not for either me or the authors of what is out there to be criticized.  In the meantime I am collecting more examples.  Thank you.

Comment: I do not see why you see I was yelling at anyone...